# Use awk with ansible to run command

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook below:

`- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    folderpath:
      folder1/des
      folder2/sdf
  tasks:
  - name: Create a symlink
    shell: "echo {{folderpath}} | awk -F'/' '{system(\"mkdir \" $1$2 );}'"
    register: result
    #- debug:
    #  msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
    with_items:
      - " {{folderpath}} "`

However when I run the playbook I get 2 folders made. The first one is :

`1- folder1des (as expected)
2- folder2 (this should ideally be folder2sdf )`

I have tried many combination and still it doesnt want to work. What do I need to have it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have ansible environment at the moment. But following should work:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create a symlink
    shell: "echo {{item}} | awk -F'/' '{system(\"mkdir \" $1$2 );}'"
    register: result
    #- debug:
    #  msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
    with_items:
      - folder1/des
      - folder2/sdf
```

Reference: [Ansible Loops Example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/lookup/items.html)

**Explanation:**
You were adding a single list object to the with_items. so in your with_items it finds only one object (which is of type list) to iterate over. Hence it runs only once. So now what I have done is I have passed a list of items to with_items that way it can iterate over the multiple items present in with_items.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it does work. Could you please help me to understand what was wrong with my script and also how I can set this up as variables

Comment: I have added the explanation for your reference. Can you accept this as answer so that others looking for solution would immediately come across this easily.

Comment: You could probably also just say `with_items: "{{ folderpath }}"`. Also, maybe `{{ item | regex_replace('/','') }}`, which means you could use `file:` rather than `shell` and skip the awk entirely. I assume folderpath is being read from somewhere? Otherwise, why define them with the slashes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    folderpath:
      folder1/des
      folder2/sdf
  tasks:
  - name: Create a symlink
    file:
      state : link
      path  : "{{ item | regex_replace('[0-9]/','_') }}"
      src   : "{{ item }}"
    with_items: " {{ folderpath }} "
```

Nothing in your given code creates symlinks. Is that really what you meant to do?

Comment: Thanks I am out of town now on leave.Will try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: Sorry I have been away for a while. Yes ideally the folder path would be read from somewhere. But for now I just want define it as a variable and then create folders at the location based on the path. For example, folder1/des would become folder_des